# How to scale the width of an image while it's height is fixed in android app?

Tags: android, layout

For example, I have a HorizontalScrollView as below:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="140dp" >
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/layout1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >
          </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Notice that the layout_height is a fixed value for the HorizontalScrollView. Inside the LinearLayout, if I wanna add some ImageViews into it. And I wanna have all this images have the same height as its parent, while their widths are scaled with the height. What should I do?